# Creating a defensive NPC warrior build

Tags: pathfinder-1e, npc, defender

Our DM is sending us to war as generals of an army each of us leading a 100-200 man squad. I am building my squad around having a ridiculously high AC.

I am equipping the squad with Full Plate +5 and tower shield +5 giving a +23 to AC from that.

I have found a few feats such as:

Coordinated Defense: Whenever you are adjacent to an ally who also has this feat, you receive a +2 competence bonus to your Combat Maneuver Defense. This bonus increases to +4 if the creature attempting the maneuver is larger than both you and your ally.

Covering:When you use the total defense action while using a light, heavy, or tower shield, you can provide a cover bonus to AC against all attacks to an adjacent ally your size or smaller. This cover bonus is equal to your shield’s shield bonus and lasts until the beginning of your next turn. your shield does not provide a cover bonus to reflex saves.

These are good but I am not sure if I could get NPC with the Covering feats as it requires a BAB of +6. A squad of 100-200 lvl 6 warriors would be a force to be reckoned with so I am not sure if our DM will be having them be that high of a level.

All information I have gathered is from http://www.d20pfsrd.com/

Comment: For less than the coast of outfitting one such soldier, you can buy a Scroll of Wind Wall and Wand of Fireball and destroy the whole unit.

Comment: @AlexP Yea but that is not fun. Yes that is the cheapest way but the fight is also meant to be fun not a one hit kill.

Comment: Damn you must have one heck of a treasure chamber to pay for all those armors. 50'000 GP per soldier?
What's your gold limit / level cap?

Comment: I am using the rules to my benefit with the leadership and having all of my followers scribing scrolls and selling them. @LouisH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [our discussion in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/conversation/creating-a-defensive-npc-warrior-build-bookmarked-for-reference):

I suggest you equip you soldiers with the following gear:

- Full Plate +5
- Tower Shield +5
- Mighty Longbow +5
- Longsword +5
- Arrows (100)
- Tanglefoot Bag (10)

The tactic is to charge into battle, throw down tanglefoot bags (Which snares the enemy - disabling their movement), and stand behind the tower shields shooting arrows into the enemy.

This provides a few benefits:

- Enemy can only retaliate with ranged attack, meaning you get cover bonus from the tower shields which causes enemies to miss, as well as deal with a high AC.
- Your troops will die less.

As for feats, it depends on how many you can get, but Dodge, and Point Blank Shot would be useful as well.